# I am very new to CMS space. Clear my few doubts listed below. How do I start developing sites in TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

**Background:**
I am a Laravel developer and now we're shifting to typo3 development. We are using version 9. I am struggling in the middle because of the lack of resources, except official documentation.

**Where I stand:**
I installed the **bootstrap extension** which is a package from Benjamin Knott. I successfully designed forms in the front-end and it's working fine. That's it with my progress.
[![front-end default form][1]][1]

**Requirement:**
My requirement is to create a front-end signup and login page for users. If the user logs in, I need to show their personal details in the front-end page. Also What I need to customize the login funcationalites?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't read minds and see unposted code, so we can't really help you.

Comment: There are at least two major points that need a long explanation in this question, not really suited for SO. How to send request? - throught browser - the question is too broad to give any good answer. How to Route request maybe? and How to render data? At least show us some code, we can't appropriatly help you. Just basically read the same docs

Comment: There's an active community in the Typo3 Slack that can help you, have a look here : https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack

Comment: Never add own code to an extension, your changes will be lost on updates. Have a look at https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/ to create a sitepackage extension for adding project dependant stuff. For an user auth you can simply use the integrated user login.

Comment: And there are also extensions for registering e.g. https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sf_register.

Comment: Too many questions in one questions. Most of your listed questions would make a good question of their own, though.

Comment: As @SybillePeters points out, you have too many questions and many of these are far too broad. If you want to get the thread reopened place a post on meta.stackoverflow.com with a link to your post and your plea to open the thread. Once done post a link to that thread here in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to read https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/. That tutorial guides you through the creation of own extensions with custom controllers. This "book" focues on the developer part and how concepts like MVC, Repositories and Domain Model Design work within TYPO3 context.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ contains further resources about PHP API and other stuff in general. E.g. plain queries, sending mails, logging, etc.